# Can someone say what i do wrong in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

In task below
[Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5/problem)
i did that query

```
SELECT CITY ,length(CITY ) from STATION where length(CITY )in(
select max(length(CITY ))from STATION union select min(length(CITY ))from STATION )Group by length(CITY )
 order by length(CITY ) desc,CITY ;
```

i recieved [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRTuz.png)
also i make another query like that

```
Select max(length(CITY)),CITY from STATION Group by length(CITY) Order by length(CITY)Desc;
```

and recieved that error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT03v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question phrases as:

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

You don't really need aggregation to achieve this task.

I think this would be simpler expressed with `union all` and two row-limiting queries (one that sorts cities by ascending length, the other by descending length):

```
(
    select city, char_length(city) cnt_chars 
    from station 
    order by char_length(city), city limit 1
) union all (
    select city, char_length(city) 
    from station 
    order by char_length(city) desc, city limit 1
)
```

If there is only one city in the table (or if all cities have the same length), then `union` might be more appropriate than `union all` (so the same city does not appear twice in the resultset).

Alternatively, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select city, cnt_chars 
from (
    select s.*,
        row_number() over(order by char_length(city), city) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by char_length(city) desc, city) rn_desc
    from station s
) s
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

Side note: `char_length()` is safer than `length()`. The former counts characters, while the latter counts bytes (if your strings have multi-byte characters, this is not what you want).

Comment: Sorry,i did not see that.In the first query that I wrote, it is impossible to somehow indicate which of the cities to choose if they have the same number of characters?

Comment: @Thebsemgoxcsa: I think you did not take the good route with `group by`. `union all` looks like the right way to go here. Note that the question itself mentions that you can use two queries (which is basically what `union all` does).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select `CITY` name and `length(CITY)` but grouping only by `length(CITY)`. In case when two or more cities have the some value for `length(CITY)` mysql does not know which of the `CITY` should be selected.

Comment: How can I choose which city to display?

Comment: mysql example (single query) `SELECT S1.CITY, length(S1.CITY)
FROM STATION AS S1
LEFT JOIN STATION AS S2 on (length(S1.CITY) = length(S2.CITY) AND S1.CITY > S2.CITY)
WHERE S2.CITY IS NULL
ORDER BY length(S1.CITY) ASC, S1.CITY ASC)`

Comment: PS: To answer the Hackerrank question you'll need to write 2 simple queries like `SELECT city, length(city) FROM station ORDER BY length(city) ASC, city ASC limit 1;
SELECT city, length(city) FROM station ORDER BY length(city) DESC, city ASC limit 1;`